# No line plot appearing using geom_line despite including group

Tags: r, ggplot2

Firstly I've attached the data frame I intend to plot, the number of points in each group is according to the beta value and not equal. They are however the same columns so I am not sure if that it okay for plotting. I am simply trying to plot the infection against time for each group according to beta. Therefore I was expecting there to be two lines on a plot.

```
structure(list(time = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 
100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 
230, 240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350, 
360, 370, 380, 390, 400, 410, 420, 430, 440, 450, 460, 470, 480, 
490, 500, 510, 520, 530, 540, 550, 560, 570, 580, 590, 600, 610, 
620, 630, 640, 650, 660, 670, 680, 690, 700, 710, 720, 730, 740, 
750, 760, 770, 780, 790, 800, 810, 820, 830, 840, 850, 860, 870, 
880, 890, 900, 910, 920, 930, 940, 950, 960, 970, 980, 990, 1000, 
1010, 1020, 1030, 1040, 1050, 1060, 1070, 1080, 1090, 1100, 1110, 
1120, 1130, 1140, 1150, 1160, 1170, 1180, 1190, 1200, 1210, 1220, 
1230, 1240, 1250, 1260, 1270, 1280, 1290, 1300, 1310, 1320, 1330, 
1340, 1350, 1360, 1370, 1380, 1390, 1400, 1410, 1420, 1430, 1440, 
1450, 1460, 1470, 1480, 1490, 1500, 1510, 1520, 1560, 1580, 1600, 
1610, 1630, 1650, 1670, 1680, 1690, 1710, 1720, 1740, 1760, 1800, 
1810, 1900, 2130, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 
110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200, 210, 220, 230, 
240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330, 340, 350, 360, 
370, 380, 390, 400, 410, 420, 430, 440, 450, 460, 470, 480, 490, 
500, 510, 520, 530, 540, 550, 560, 570, 580, 590, 600, 610, 620, 
630, 640, 650, 660, 670, 680, 690, 700, 710, 720, 730, 740, 750, 
760, 770, 780, 790, 800, 810, 820, 830, 840, 850, 860, 870, 880, 
890, 900, 910, 920, 930, 940, 950, 960, 970, 980, 990, 1000, 
1010, 1020, 1030, 1040, 1050, 1060, 1070, 1080, 1090, 1100, 1110, 
1120, 1130, 1140, 1150, 1160, 1170, 1180, 1190, 1200, 1210, 1220, 
1230, 1240, 1250, 1260, 1270, 1280, 1290, 1300, 1310, 1320, 1330, 
1340, 1350, 1360, 1370, 1380, 1390, 1400, 1410, 1420, 1430, 1440, 
1450, 1460, 1470, 1480, 1490, 1500, 1510, 1520, 1530, 1540, 1550, 
1560, 1570, 1580, 1590, 1600, 1610, 1620, 1630, 1640, 1650, 1660, 
1670, 1680, 1690, 1700, 1710, 1720, 1730, 1740, 1750, 1760, 1770, 
1780, 1790, 1800, 1810, 1820, 1830, 1840, 1850, 1860, 1870, 1880, 
1890, 1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 
2000, 2010, 2020, 2030, 2040, 2050, 2060, 2070, 2080, 2090, 2100, 
2110, 2120, 2130, 2140, 2150, 2160, 2170, 2180, 2190, 2200, 2210, 
2220, 2230, 2240, 2250, 2260, 2270, 2280, 2290, 2300, 2310, 2320, 
2330, 2340, 2350, 2360, 2370, 2380, 2390, 2400, 2410, 2420, 2430, 
2440, 2450, 2460, 2470, 2480, 2490, 2500, 2510, 2520, 2530, 2540, 
2550, 2560, 2570, 2580, 2590, 2600, 2610, 2620, 2630, 2640, 2650, 
2660, 2670, 2680, 2690, 2700, 2710, 2720, 2730, 2740, 2750, 2760, 
2770, 2780, 2790, 2800, 2810, 2820, 2830, 2840, 2850, 2860, 2870, 
2880, 2890, 2900, 2910, 2920, 2930, 2940, 2950, 2960, 2970, 2980, 
2990, 3000, 3010, 3020, 3030, 3040, 3050, 3060, 3070, 3080, 3090, 
3100, 3110, 3120, 3130, 3140, 3150, 3160, 3170, 3180, 3190, 3200, 
3210, 3220, 3230, 3240, 3250, 3260, 3270, 3280, 3290, 3300, 3310, 
3320, 3330, 3340, 3350, 3360, 3370, 3380, 3390, 3400, 3410, 3420, 
3430, 3440, 3450, 3460, 3470, 3480, 3490, 3500, 3510, 3520, 3530, 
3540, 3550, 3560, 3570, 3580, 3590, 3600, 3610, 3620, 3630, 3640, 
3650, 3660, 3670, 3680, 3690, 3700, 3710, 3720, 3730, 3740, 3750, 
3760, 3770, 3780, 3790, 3800, 3810, 3820, 3830, 3840, 3850, 3860, 
3870, 3880, 3890, 3900, 3910, 3920, 3930, 3940, 3950, 3960, 3970, 
3980, 3990, 4000, 4010, 4020, 4030, 4040, 4050, 4060, 4070, 4080, 
4090, 4100, 4110, 4120, 4130, 4140, 4150, 4160, 4170, 4180, 4190, 
4200, 4210, 4220, 4230, 4240, 4250, 4260, 4270, 4280, 4290, 4300, 
4310, 4320, 4330, 4340, 4350, 4360, 4370, 4380, 4390, 4400, 4410, 
4420, 4430, 4440, 4450, 4460, 4470, 4480, 4490, 4500, 4510, 4520, 
4530, 4540, 4550, 4560, 4570, 4580, 4590, 4600, 4610, 4620, 4630, 
4640, 4650, 4660, 4670, 4680, 4690, 4700, 4710, 4720, 4730, 4740, 
4750, 4760, 4770, 4780, 4790, 4800, 4810, 4820, 4830, 4840, 4850, 
4860, 4870, 4880, 4890, 4900, 4910, 4920, 4930, 4940, 4950, 4960, 
4970, 4980, 4990, 5000, 5010, 5020, 5030, 5040, 5050, 5060, 5070, 
5080, 5090, 5100, 5110, 5120, 5130, 5140, 5150, 5160, 5170, 5180, 
5190, 5200, 5210, 5220, 5230, 5240, 5250, 5260, 5270, 5280, 5290, 
5300, 5310, 5320, 5330, 5340, 5350, 5360, 5370, 5380, 5390, 5400, 
5410, 5420, 5430, 5440, 5450, 5460, 5470, 5480, 5490, 5500, 5510, 
5520, 5530, 5540, 5550, 5560, 5570, 5580, 5590, 5600, 5610, 5620, 
5630, 5640, 5650, 5660, 5670, 5680, 5690, 5700, 5710, 5720, 5730, 
5740, 5750, 5760, 5770, 5780, 5790, 5800, 5810, 5820, 5830, 5840, 
5850, 5860, 5870, 5880, 5890, 5900, 5910, 5920, 5930, 5950, 5960, 
5970, 5980, 5990, 6000, 6010, 6020, 6030, 6040, 6050, 6060, 6070, 
6080, 6090, 6100, 6110, 6120, 6130, 6140, 6150, 6160, 6170, 6180, 
6190, 6200, 6210, 6220, 6230, 6240, 6250, 6260, 6270, 6280, 6290, 
6300, 6310, 6320, 6330, 6340, 6350, 6360, 6370, 6380, 6390, 6400, 
6410, 6420, 6430, 6440, 6450, 6460, 6470, 6480, 6490, 6500, 6510, 
6520, 6530, 6540, 6550, 6560, 6570, 6580, 6590, 6600, 6610, 6620, 
6630, 6640, 6650, 6660, 6670, 6680, 6690, 6700, 6710, 6720, 6730, 
6740, 6750, 6760, 6780, 6790, 6800, 6810, 6820, 6830, 6840, 6850, 
6860, 6870, 6880, 6890, 6900, 6910, 6920, 6930, 6950, 6980, 6990, 
7000, 7010, 7020, 7030, 7040, 7050, 7060, 7070, 7080, 7090, 7100, 
7110, 7120, 7130, 7140, 7150, 7160, 7170, 7180, 7190, 7200, 7210, 
7220, 7230, 7240, 7260, 7270, 7290, 7300, 7310, 7320, 7330, 7340, 
7350, 7360, 7370, 7380, 7390, 7400, 7410, 7420, 7430, 7450, 7460, 
7470, 7500, 7510, 7520, 7530, 7540, 7550, 7560, 7570, 7580, 7590, 
7600, 7610, 7620, 7640, 7660, 7670, 7700, 7710, 7720, 7730, 7740, 
7760, 7770, 7790, 7800, 7830, 7840, 7870, 7880, 7890, 7910, 7920, 
7930, 7940, 7970, 7990, 8000, 8030, 8040, 8060, 8080, 8130, 8170, 
8190, 8200, 8290, 8350, 8370, 8410, 8500, 8540, 8590, 8740, 8810, 
8850, 8940, 9090, 9110, 9140, 9290, 9720, 10220), infected = c(1, 
1.19373097189505, 1.42494009931824, 1.70085496820616, 2.03008733852723, 
2.42289413533513, 2.89148590996926, 3.45039066080758, 4.11688188860957, 
4.91148071775759, 5.85854274974797, 6.9869408879324, 8.3308554727812, 
9.93068239069737, 11.8340679365951, 14.0970755270874, 16.7854830770867, 
19.9761999205677, 23.7587772527675, 28.2369646004177, 33.5302349909581, 
39.7751614814575, 47.126476087645, 55.757578541104, 65.8601884487318, 
77.6427557685863, 91.3271721608325, 107.143278649984, 125.320671465086, 
146.077405278585, 169.605423494471, 196.052945176888, 225.504620206542, 
257.960992604213, 293.319579166864, 331.360488301079, 371.739726239488, 
413.992928558708, 457.551091975817, 501.768059961208, 545.957390444562, 
589.434349362065, 631.557683812026, 671.76587626694, 709.60375131697, 
744.737231793397, 776.956160528942, 806.166882610512, 832.377385899268, 
855.678149751681, 876.221588630421, 894.202339055359, 909.839868353674, 
923.364164113431, 935.004695266985, 944.982450234318, 953.504639252043, 
960.761559445912, 966.925120313071, 972.148577326561, 976.567094811725, 
980.298837839799, 983.446366059971, 986.098165074237, 988.330201619796, 
990.207427961075, 991.785189993633, 993.110514444735, 994.223265007027, 
995.157166837881, 995.940704898573, 996.597905120795, 997.149009155157, 
997.611054056747, 997.99836811508, 998.322993435576, 998.595045030529, 
998.823015216098, 999.014031126732, 999.174072204547, 999.308153630459, 
999.420480852474, 999.514579640584, 999.59340545687, 999.659435369433, 
999.714745253347, 999.761074603705, 999.79988092747, 999.832385374954, 
999.859611011495, 999.882414909109, 999.90151505096, 999.917512883497, 
999.930912217838, 999.942135069615, 999.951534931953, 999.95940789666, 
999.966001971883, 999.971524888277, 999.97615063858, 999.98002495589, 
999.983269902743, 999.985987715214, 999.988264022904, 999.99017054609, 
999.991767354908, 999.993104761643, 999.994224905709, 999.995163081205, 
999.995948848853, 999.996606967325, 999.997158173297, 999.997619834803, 
999.998006498449, 999.998330347747, 999.998601586993, 999.998828762786, 
999.999019033323, 999.999178393941, 999.999311866025, 999.999423655227, 
999.999517283984, 999.999595702503, 999.999661381727, 999.999716391186, 
999.999762464211, 999.999801052549, 999.999833372107, 999.999860441265, 
999.999883112965, 999.999902101585, 999.999918005452, 999.999931325692, 
999.999942482023, 999.999951825977, 999.99995965198, 999.999966206627, 
999.999971696454, 999.999976294443, 999.999980145476, 999.999983370898, 
999.999986072342, 999.999988334928, 999.999990229952, 999.999991817123, 
999.999993146454, 999.999994259831, 999.999995192338, 999.999995973356, 
999.999996627495, 999.999997175368, 999.999997634237, 999.999998018562, 
999.999999024971, 999.999999316031, 999.999999520206, 999.99999959815, 
999.999999718108, 999.999999802257, 999.999999861286, 999.999999883821, 
999.999999902694, 999.999999931741, 999.99999994283, 999.999999959896, 
999.999999971868, 999.999999986157, 999.999999988406, 999.999999997649, 
999.99999999996, 1, 1.04056353104213, 1.08277067876057, 1.12668789419145, 
1.17238430275601, 1.21993181088251, 1.26940521679498, 1.32088232562485, 
1.37444406900632, 1.43017462932211, 1.48816156877142, 1.54849596343766, 
1.61127254253929, 1.67658983305277, 1.74455030990268, 1.81526055192012, 
1.88883140377663, 1.9653781441069, 2.04502066004023, 2.12788362836669, 
2.21409670357045, 2.30379471296939, 2.39711785920635, 2.49421193034391, 
2.59522851782121, 2.70032524253757, 2.80966598933413, 2.92342115015109, 
3.04176787614413, 3.16489033904978, 3.29298000209525, 3.42623590075385, 
3.56486493365245, 3.70908216394252, 3.85911113145071, 4.01518417592955, 
4.17754277173191, 4.34643787423664, 4.52213027835493, 4.70489098944872, 
4.89500160699349, 5.09275472131786, 5.29845432375121, 5.51241623050869, 
5.73496852063925, 5.96645198835791, 6.20722061007685, 6.45764202644199, 
6.7180980396719, 6.98898512648389, 7.27071496687792, 7.56371498903238, 
7.86842893054654, 8.18531741624232, 8.51485855271242, 8.85754853977336, 
9.21390229894933, 9.58445411907618, 9.96975831907389, 10.3703899278906, 
10.7869453815697, 11.2200432373373, 11.6703249045416, 12.1384553922127, 
12.6251240729304, 13.1310454626105, 13.6569600157257, 14.2036349353821, 
14.7718649975627, 15.3624733887352, 15.9763125558922, 16.6142650679576, 
17.2772444873433, 17.9661962502799, 18.6820985543763, 19.4259632516723, 
20.1988367452541, 21.0018008872881, 21.8359738760982, 22.702511149671, 
23.6026062727118, 24.5374918140987, 25.5084402112879, 26.5167646179135, 
27.5638197304943, 28.6510025898144, 29.7797533521792, 30.9515560253618, 
32.1679391636564, 33.4304765160319, 34.7407876209413, 36.1005383408902, 
37.5114413293923, 38.9752564224585, 40.4937909462621, 42.0688999321175, 
43.7024862293824, 45.3965005063734, 47.1529411288489, 48.9738539050847, 
50.8613316860391, 52.8175138085887, 54.8445853693058, 56.9447763157701, 
59.1203603419426, 61.3736535737092, 63.7070130303153, 66.1228348470816, 
68.6235522445187, 71.211633228756, 73.8895780080808, 76.6599161103565, 
79.5252031861711, 82.4880174827657, 85.5509559741274, 88.7166301331137, 
91.9876613321212, 95.3666758596346, 98.8562995410123, 102.459151953088, 
106.177840223619, 110.014952408305, 113.973050440021, 118.05466264714, 
122.262275840255, 126.598326969408, 131.065194356919, 135.665188514306, 
140.400542555327, 145.273402221143, 150.285815537729, 155.439722130104, 
160.736942222638, 166.179165359554, 171.767938884828, 177.504656225882, 
183.390545030797, 189.426655214091, 195.613846971466, 201.95277882919, 
208.443895798844, 215.087417713089, 221.883327822603, 228.831361738541, 
235.930996808463, 243.181442016794, 250.581628503199, 258.130200793887, 
265.825508841567, 273.665600969548, 281.648217814235, 289.770787357878, 
298.030421139972, 306.423911730944, 314.947731545892, 323.598033068941, 
332.370650550469, 341.261103229867, 350.264600125899, 359.376046424978, 
368.59005148511, 377.900938459768, 387.302755531929, 396.789288733884, 
406.354076313583, 415.990424593267, 425.691425251274, 435.44997394333, 
445.258790165646, 455.110438248851, 464.997349359546, 474.911844375112, 
484.846157487707, 494.792460385108, 504.742886849523, 514.689557610707, 
524.624605286787, 534.540199245197, 544.428570217039, 554.282034501027, 
564.093017597865, 573.854077122395, 583.557924848991, 593.197447755395, 
602.76572794118, 612.256061309324, 621.66197491254, 630.977242880023, 
640.195900854809, 649.312258886795, 658.320912741494, 667.216753599427, 
675.994976135735, 684.65108498361, 693.180899598694, 701.580557554205, 
709.8465163083, 717.975553495912, 725.964765806838, 733.811566520341, 
741.513681773667, 749.069145647909, 756.476294159392, 763.733758248312, 
770.840455858802, 777.795583205858, 784.598605324896, 791.249245998959, 
797.747477157111, 804.093507835135, 810.287772786716, 816.330920829576, 
822.223803006959, 827.967460640317, 833.563113344172, 839.012147069067, 
844.31610223323, 849.476661998287, 854.495640738966, 859.374972751453, 
864.116701239831, 868.722967614962, 873.196001135292, 877.538108914355, 
881.751666315318, 885.839107748735, 889.802917885748, 893.645623295346, 
897.369784510975, 900.977988528684, 904.472841736299, 907.856963270562, 
911.132978796996, 914.303514705316, 917.371192711459, 920.338624855904, 
923.208408886678, 925.983124014428, 928.665327026107, 931.257548743167, 
933.762290809661, 936.182022795327, 938.519179598494, 940.77615913359, 
942.955320288049, 945.058981133516, 947.089417376463, 949.048861033581, 
950.939499317677, 952.763473720128, 954.522879276441, 956.219764001848, 
957.856128484423, 959.433925623643, 960.955060502895, 962.421390384905, 
963.834724819641, 965.196825854734, 966.509408339018, 967.774140310291, 
968.992643458931, 970.166493659468, 971.297221562743, 972.386313241713, 
973.435210884456, 974.445313528329, 975.417977829699, 976.354518864022, 
977.256210951475, 978.124288503666, 978.959946887344, 979.764343301326, 
980.538597663171, 981.283793502455, 982.000978857738, 982.691167174612, 
983.355338202428, 983.994438887561, 984.609384261268, 985.201058320389, 
985.77031489935, 986.317978532064, 986.844845302536, 987.351683683067, 
987.839235359141, 988.308216040182, 988.75931625548, 989.193202134711, 
989.610516172556, 990.011877977032, 990.39788500121, 990.769113258098, 
991.126118018503, 991.469434491775, 991.799578489386, 992.11704707133, 
992.422319175409, 992.715856229475, 992.998102746767, 993.26948690449, 
993.530421105826, 993.781302525589, 994.022513639755, 994.254422739123, 
994.477384427374, 994.691740103819, 994.897818431122, 995.09593578831, 
995.286396709391, 995.469494307883, 995.645510687598, 995.814717340001, 
995.977375528477, 996.133736659832, 996.284042643378, 996.428526237913, 
996.567411386936, 996.700913542424, 996.829239977495, 996.952590088275, 
997.071155685287, 997.185121274673, 997.294664329559, 997.399955551855, 
997.501159124803, 997.598432956541, 997.691928914986, 997.781793054305, 
997.868165833241, 997.951182325574, 998.030972422959, 998.107661030403, 
998.181368254628, 998.252209585547, 998.320296071107, 998.385734485702, 
998.44862749239, 998.509073799129, 998.56716830923, 998.623002266238, 
998.676663393426, 998.728236028102, 998.777801250906, 998.825437010282, 
998.871218242276, 998.915216985867, 998.957502493941, 998.998141340115, 
999.037197521519, 999.074732557713, 999.110805585864, 999.145473452322, 
999.178790800729, 999.210810156789, 999.24158200982, 999.271154891205, 
999.299575449861, 999.326888524832, 999.353137215118, 999.378362946839, 
999.40260553783, 999.425903259774, 999.448292897956, 999.469809808725, 
999.49048797476, 999.510360058218, 999.529457451836, 999.547810328079, 
999.565447686397, 999.58239739866, 999.598686252859, 999.614339995108, 
999.629383370042, 999.643840159655, 999.657733220634, 999.671084520268, 
999.683915170954, 999.696245463388, 999.708094898459, 999.719482217922, 
999.730425433882, 999.740941857134, 999.751048124416, 999.760760224599, 
999.770093523864, 999.779062789915, 999.787682215237, 999.795965439469, 
999.8039255709, 999.811575207135, 999.818926454964, 999.825990949449, 
999.832779872286, 999.83930396944, 999.845573568107, 999.851598593009, 
999.857388582063, 999.862952701438, 999.868299760027, 999.873438223358, 
999.878376226966, 999.883121589242, 999.887681823782, 999.892064151265, 
999.896275510855, 999.900322571171, 999.904211740826, 999.907949178556, 
999.911540802956, 999.914992301837, 999.918309141218, 999.921496573968, 
999.924559648117, 999.927503214831, 999.930331936094, 999.933050292073, 
999.935662588211, 999.938172962035, 999.940585389701, 999.942903692287, 
999.945131541835, 999.947272467165, 999.949329859457, 999.951306977618, 
999.953206953436, 999.955032796543, 999.956787399173, 999.95847354074, 
999.960093892239, 999.961651020475, 999.963147392121, 999.96458537763, 
999.965967254981, 999.967295213288, 999.968571356268, 999.969797705566, 
999.970976203963, 999.972108718445, 999.973197043163, 999.974242902276, 
999.975247952674, 999.976213786608, 999.977141934211, 999.978033865918, 
999.978890994794, 999.979714678777, 999.980506222824, 999.981266880979, 
999.98199785836, 999.982700313064, 999.983375358006, 999.984024062681, 
999.984647454852, 999.985246522187, 999.985822213816, 999.986375441838, 
999.986907082763, 999.987417978904, 999.987908939708, 999.988380743041, 
999.988834136417, 999.989269838184, 999.989688538663, 999.990090901237, 
999.990477563408, 999.990849137803, 999.991206213145, 999.991549355185, 
999.9918791076, 999.992195992855, 999.992500513026, 999.992793150601, 
999.993074369241, 999.993344614514, 999.993604314605, 999.993853880989, 
999.994093709088, 999.994324178892, 999.994545655567, 999.994758490027, 
999.994963019497, 999.995159568042, 999.99534844708, 999.995529955882, 
999.995704382037, 999.995872001915, 999.996033081102, 999.996187874819, 
999.996336628331, 999.996479577329, 999.996616948312, 999.996748958936, 
999.996875818368, 999.996997727611, 999.997114879826, 999.997227460635, 
999.99733564842, 999.997439614599, 999.997539523904, 999.997635534638, 
999.997727798925, 999.997816462957, 999.997901667219, 999.997983546714, 
999.998062231177, 999.998137845283, 999.998210508839, 999.998280336979, 
999.998347440344, 999.998411925257, 999.998473893894, 999.998533444441, 
999.998590671255, 999.998645665012, 999.998698512847, 999.998749298495, 
999.998798102427, 999.998845001972, 999.998890071439, 999.998933382241, 
999.998975003003, 999.999014999673, 999.999053435623, 999.999090371756, 
999.999125866596, 999.999159976384, 999.999192755166, 999.999224254879, 
999.999254525435, 999.999283614796, 999.999311569054, 999.999338432502, 
999.999364247706, 999.999389055567, 999.999412895396, 999.999435804964, 
999.999457820572, 999.999478977104, 999.999499308081, 999.999518845718, 
999.999537620972, 999.999555663592, 999.999573002166, 999.999589664167, 
999.999605675996, 999.999621063023, 999.999635849628, 999.999650059242, 
999.999663714379, 999.999676836674, 999.999689446922, 999.999701565101, 
999.999713210413, 999.999724401311, 999.999735155525, 999.999745490097, 
999.9997554214, 999.999764965171, 999.999774136532, 999.999782950015, 
999.999791419585, 999.99979955866, 999.999807380139, 999.999814896414, 
999.999822119394, 999.999829060524, 999.999835730803, 999.999842140798, 
999.999848300668, 999.999854220171, 999.999859908688, 999.999865375231, 
999.999870628463, 999.999875676707, 999.999880527963, 999.999885189915, 
999.999889669953, 999.999893975174, 999.999898112399, 999.999902088185, 
999.99990590883, 999.999909580389, 999.999913108679, 999.99991649929, 
999.999919757596, 999.999922888758, 999.999925897738, 999.999928789304, 
999.999931568037, 999.999934238341, 999.999936804446, 999.999939270418, 
999.999941640165, 999.999943917441, 999.999948208874, 999.99995022983, 
999.999952171927, 999.99995403824, 999.999955831727, 999.99995755523, 
999.99995921148, 999.999960803101, 999.999962332614, 999.999963802445, 
999.99996521492, 999.999966572279, 999.999967876672, 999.999969130165, 
999.999970334746, 999.999971492323, 999.999972604729, 999.999973673728, 
999.999974701013, 999.999975688212, 999.99997663689, 999.999977548549, 
999.999978424633, 999.999979266532, 999.999980075579, 999.999980853055, 
999.999981600194, 999.999982318178, 999.999983008146, 999.99998367119, 
999.999984308361, 999.999984920669, 999.999985509084, 999.999986074538, 
999.999986617928, 999.999987140114, 999.999987641923, 999.999988124151, 
999.999988587562, 999.99998903289, 999.999989460841, 999.999989872093, 
999.999990267297, 999.999990647079, 999.999991012042, 999.999991362764, 
999.9999916998, 999.999992023685, 999.999992334931, 999.999992634032, 
999.999992921461, 999.999993197675, 999.999993463111, 999.999993718189, 
999.999993963313, 999.999994198872, 999.99999442524, 999.999994642774, 
999.99999485182, 999.999995052709, 999.999995245758, 999.999995431275, 
999.999995609553, 999.999995780874, 999.999995945509, 999.999996103721, 
999.999996255759, 999.999996401864, 999.999996542268, 999.999996677193, 
999.999996806853, 999.999996931454, 999.999997051193, 999.999997166259, 
999.999997276835, 999.999997383096, 999.999997485211, 999.999997583342, 
999.999997677643, 999.999997768264, 999.999997855349, 999.999997939036, 
999.999998096741, 999.999998171009, 999.999998242378, 999.999998310963, 
999.999998376872, 999.999998440208, 999.999998501073, 999.999998559563, 
999.999998615771, 999.999998669785, 999.999998721692, 999.999998771573, 
999.999998819508, 999.999998865572, 999.999998909839, 999.999998952379, 
999.999999032543, 999.999999141435, 999.999999174937, 999.999999207132, 
999.999999238071, 999.999999267803, 999.999999296374, 999.99999932383, 
999.999999350215, 999.999999375571, 999.999999399937, 999.999999423352, 
999.999999445854, 999.999999467477, 999.999999488257, 999.999999508226, 
999.999999527415, 999.999999545856, 999.999999563577, 999.999999580607, 
999.999999596972, 999.999999612699, 999.999999627812, 999.999999642335, 
999.999999656292, 999.999999669704, 999.999999682592, 999.999999694978, 
999.999999718318, 999.99999972931, 999.999999750023, 999.999999759778, 
999.999999769151, 999.999999778159, 999.999999786816, 999.999999795135, 
999.999999803129, 999.999999810811, 999.999999818193, 999.999999825288, 
999.999999832105, 999.999999838657, 999.999999844952, 999.999999851002, 
999.999999856817, 999.999999867773, 999.999999872933, 999.999999877891, 
999.999999891635, 999.999999895864, 999.999999899927, 999.999999903832, 
999.999999907585, 999.999999911191, 999.999999914656, 999.999999917987, 
999.999999921187, 999.999999924262, 999.999999927218, 999.999999930058, 
999.999999932787, 999.99999993793, 999.99999994268, 999.999999944916, 
999.999999951116, 999.999999953024, 999.999999954857, 999.999999956618, 
999.999999958311, 999.999999961501, 999.999999963003, 999.999999965834, 
999.999999967168, 999.999999970863, 999.999999972, 999.999999975152, 
999.999999976121, 999.999999977053, 999.999999978809, 999.999999979636, 
999.99999998043, 999.999999981194, 999.999999983311, 999.999999984588, 
999.999999985189, 999.999999986856, 999.999999987369, 999.999999988336, 
999.999999989228, 999.999999991172, 999.999999992471, 999.999999993047, 
999.999999993319, 999.99999999533, 999.999999996322, 999.999999996604, 
999.999999997104, 999.999999997976, 999.999999998274, 999.999999998585, 
999.999999999221, 999.999999999411, 999.999999999497, 999.999999999649, 
999.999999999807, 999.999999999821, 999.999999999842, 999.999999999913, 
999.999999999984, 999.999999999998), beta = c("5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1")), row.names = c(NA, -972L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried using ggplot to perform this intended output as follows:

```
ggplot()+
 geom_line(data=plottable,
  aes(x=time, y=infected),
  group=beta,
  colour=beta,
  size=1)
```

With plottable being the dataframe above. However the output I receive is a basic plot with no lines

[image]

I thought by adding group I would fix this error, but that has not happened. I would really appreciate if anyone knew the reason why this is not working.

Comment: Put `group` and `color` inside aes().

Comment: Sorry, such a simple fix, I should of tried this, thank you!